# How to programmatically set node alias on node save

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks, path-aliases

I need to set a special path alias for nodes created by users in the `template.php` file of my theme. the [pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module is enabled.
I already tried the solutions that are given in the following links

1. [Create path alias programatically when node is created](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13170/create-path-alias-programatically-when-node-is-created)
2. [How To Set Node Path/Alias Programatically](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3698/how-to-set-node-path-alias-programatically)
3. [Programmatically set path alias](https://www.drupal.org/node/714672)

But none of them worked. Here is a few codes I tried but I failed.

```
function THEME_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3=NULL, $a4=NULL){
    if($node->type == "image"){
        switch ($op){
            case "insert":
                $default_node_path = 'node/'.$node->nid;
                $alternate_url = "SOME SPECIAL PATH";
                path_set_alias($default_node_path, $alternate_url, 0, '');
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

or this one

```
function THEME_insert($node){
    $path = "SOME SPECIAL PATH";
    $node->path = array('alias' => $path, 'pathauto' => FALSE);
}

function THEME_node_insert($node){
    $path = "SOME SPECIAL PATH";
    $node->path = array('alias' => $path, 'pathauto' => FALSE);
}
```

or

```
function THEME_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3=NULL, $a4=NULL){
    if($node->type == "image"){
        switch ($op){
            case "insert":
                $node->path = t("SOME SPECIAL PATH");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do set path alias programmatically ?

---

**UPDATE**

I tried this code that recommended by [@Ajit S](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/6461/ajits) and it didn't work again

```
<?php
    function THEME_node_insert($node){
        $alias = "arar/".$node->nid;
        $lang_code = "en";
        $path = array(
          'source' => "node/{$node->nid}",
          'alias' => $alias,  // Any alias that you want to set.
          'language' => $lang_code,  // Optional, if you are working on a multilingual site.
        );
        path_save($path);
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create path alias programatically when node is created](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13170/create-path-alias-programatically-when-node-is-created)

Comment: @leymannx as I mentioned in the question, I already check that question and it didn't solve the problem

Comment: Hi, @drupalist. You didn't specify a version so I'll assume it's 7.x. `hook_nodeapi()` isn't a valid function in 7.x. Please read about the 7.x equivalent(s) at this link: https://www.drupal.org/update/modules/6/7#remove_op. Also please note the limitations of `hook_insert()` as noted by @kiamlaluno here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13170/create-path-alias-programatically-when-node-is-created#comment13809_13516.

Comment: @othermachines sorry it is my mistake. Yes it is `7`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [hook_insert](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_insert/7)

```
/**
 * Implements hook_insert().
 */
function mymodule_insert($node) {
    // Set the URL alias
    if (empty($node->path['alias'])) {
        $node->path['alias'] = 'slug/' . $node->nid;
    }
}
```

if url has no alias then we can create it

```
if( urlAlias == '' )
path_set_alias($default_node_path, $alternate_url, 0, '');
```

Comment: `hook_insert()` is for modules implementing a content type.

Comment: `hook_insert()` is for any module that wants to chip in when content is being saved.  The example given for this is when adding a new content type that needs handling in the save process, but that is not the only use for the hook.

Answer (score 6):

Path alias could be set using the path module in the core. Just call [`path_save`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/path_save/7) the following from a function (or hook) of your choice. In your case I'd recommend you to implement the following code in `hook_node_insert`, because it is called after a node has been saved, and the node will have a valid nid.

```
// Assuming you have a $node object already.
$path = array(
  'source' => "node/{$node->nid}",
  'alias' => $alias,  // Any alias that you want to set.
  'language' => $lang_code,  // Optional, if you are working on a multilingual site.
);
path_save($path);
```

If you have global redirect set, the node page will be redirected to the alias.

Comment: I tried your code in `hook_node_insert` but it didn't work!

Comment: Did you edit the node and check if the alias was set? Also, it would be good if you could verify if the entry was made in the url_alias table in the database.

Comment: No I just created a new node and checked the url via browser

Comment: Can you check by editing the node to make sure if the alias is set. Also, install [globalredirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect) and try again.

Comment: global redirect is already installed. I just checked editing a content and it has no alias at all

Comment: Strange! It is working at my end. Could you edit the question and include the code which you are trying? Then maybe it would be easier to debug

Comment: ok I updated the question

Comment: Just to clarify: you can't implement node CRUD hooks in a theme @Drupalist

Comment: @Clive So I must create a module to do this yes? thank you very useful advice

Comment: Yes move the `hook_node_insert` implementation to a module.

Comment: Afterwards, I had to `$node->path = $path; node_save($node);` or else the path would not show up on the node edit form.

Answer (score 6):

None of the hook_nodeapi implementations will work, that hook was removed in Drupal 7.

Your other attempts are failing because you're trying to implement the hooks in a theme - themes can implement theme hooks, hook_theme, and alter hooks only.

Move your code to a module, and you'll have better luck.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I just discovered a great way to do this for a Drupal 7 site:

1. In `hook_node_presave`, set `$node->path['pathauto']` equal to 0 if `$node->original` is not yet set (that is, if this is a node insert and not a node update). This prevents an automatic alias from being applied if one normally would.
2. In `hook_node_insert', create the new path using`path_save`and make sure the source is`node/nid`.

Here is an example for a custom module called `mymodule` assuming you want this for all new `mytype` nodes with a 'my_field`value not equal to`1`, and that you want to customize the alias as`mycustomalias/my_field/nid`:

```
function mymodule_node_presave($node) {
  // Add any conditions that determine whether this node needs a custom alias.
  if (
    $node->type == 'mytype' &&
    !isset($node->original) &&
    isset($node->field_my_field['und'][0]['value']) &&
    $node->field_my_field['und'][0]['value'] != 1
  ) {
    $node->path['pathauto'] == 0;
  }
}

function mymodule_node_insert($node) {
  // Add the same conditions as you had in mymodule_node_presave, except you don't need to check for $node->original.
  if (
    $node->type == 'mytype' &&
    isset($node->field_my_field['und'][0]['value']) &&
    $node->field_my_field['und'][0]['value'] != 1
  ) {
    // Create a $new_path array that contains the source of your node and the custom alias you want.
    $new_path = [
      'source' => 'node/' . $node->nid,
      'alias' => 'mycustomalias/' . $node->field_my_field['und'][0]['value'] . '/' . $node->nid],
    ];
    // Save the path. By using the variable above rather than putting the array into the function call, you avoid PHP errors.
    path_save($new_path);
  }
}
```